# Array of Objects Won't Clear

Tags: javascript, arrays, instance-variables

I have an array that's a property called `.phrases` of an object called a Passage.  I have a function that's a property of that same object.  In the function, I have code like this:

```
var returnPassage=new Passage();
returnPassage.phrases=[];
console.log(returnPassage.phrases);
```

The console log in Google Chrome shows an empty array on one level, but if I click the drop-down it shows that the array hasn't changed at all.  This is true whether I try to clear the array with `.pop()` or `.splice()` or by replacing it with a `new Array()`.  It's also, bizarrely(!!!) true if I do this:

```
var returnPassage=new Passage();
returnPassage.phrases=null;
returnPassage.phrases=[];
console.log(returnPassage.phrases);
```

The console log shows the array same as original, not a blank array like i expect.  What could possibly be going on here???

Comment: Show us your `Passage`?

Comment: Aaah just figured it out!  It's the way Chrome's log works.  Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281186/chrome-devtools-inconsistency-array-length.

Answer (score 0):

What could be going on is that phrases is just a property with a getter only, without seeing the `Passage` object, it is hard to say what is going on.

You can imagine having a setup like this inside your `Passage` object

```js
function Passage() {
 Object.defineProperty(this, 'phrases', {
   get: function() {
     return ['phrase 1', 'phrase2'];
    },
    set: function() {
     // no setter
    }
  })
}

var passage = new Passage();
passage.phrases = null;
passage.phrases = [];
console.log(passage.phrases);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what was happening: Chrome was logging the array and showing it in the top line, then my method changed it, then the drop-down shows it the most recent way it has been. So it's not a problem with how the javascript was working, it's a problem with how I was reading Chrome's display.