# Combining Javascript array incorrect amount of objects

Tags: javascript

I have two SQL queries which I combine to create a single array with a number of objects. I'm able to do so with the .push() method. (It is javascript within the Rollbase platform, therefor the query formats).

However, I can't get my head around the results. The object is correct and consists of the correct objects and values. However it says that it holds 8 objects, while there are 13. Also it only seems to count the values from the first query:

Code snippet:

```
rbf_selectQuery("SELECT name,id,Ppm_objecten,'object' FROM pm_objecten", 2000, function(values) {
    var arr = values;
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        rbf_selectQuery("SELECT name,id,R82743 AS Ppm_objecten,'activiteit' FROM pm_activiteit WHERE R82743=" + values[i][1], 2000, function(values2) {
            for (n = 0; n < values2.length; n++) {
                if (values2.length > 0) {
                    arr.push(values2[n]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    var length = arr.length;
    console.log(arr.length);
    console.log(arr);
    options.success({
        total: length,
        data: arr
    });
});
```

Output:

```
(8) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
0: (4) ["Damwand", 72076, 68241, "object"]
1: (4) ["Fietsparkeergarage", 68238, 72042, "object"]
2: (4) ["Constructie", 68241, 68238, "object"]
3: (4) ["Systeem Fietsparkeergarage", 72042, null, "object"]
4: (4) ["Test Bovenliggend", 72043, null, "object"]
5: (4) ["Object onder Boven", 72074, 72043, "object"]
6: (4) ["Object onder onder", 72075, 72074, "object"]
7: (4) ["Test", 78394, null, "object"]
8: (4) ["Opstellen van een projectmanagementplan (PMP)", 74191, 68238, "activiteit"]
9: (4) ["Ontwerpen DO Fietsparkeergarage", 68248, 68238, "activiteit"]
10: (4) ["Ontwerpen UO Fietsparkeergarage", 68251, 68238, "activiteit"]
11: (4) ["Afdichting dek 80% gereed", 88220, 72042, "activiteit"]
12: (4) ["Afdichting dek resterende 20%", 88221, 72042, "activiteit"]
length: 13
__proto__: Array(0)
```

The thing I just don't understand is why the object holds (8) objects, as you can see on the first line. And arr.length outputs 8. But I see and need these 13 objects... Can somebody please ellaborate what I'm missing? When outputting typeOf() they are all of the type object..

Comment: `length` says 13 not 8

Comment: Correct, but console.log(arr.length); outputs 8. That is why I am confused.

Comment: Is this related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281186/chrome-devtools-inconsistency-array-length ?

Comment: I've slightly edited the code snippet. I found that it was not the correct version. @barbsan this post is helpful thank you!

Comment: It IS related - you call those `console.log`s and `option.success` in callback of first query, when queries in loop didn't return their result yet. At the time you expand your array the extra items have been pushed and you see all of them. You need [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @barbsan I was led in the right direction. Since I'm new to Javascript, I didn't know this yet. By setting a new Promise which awaits the result from the query, I am able to do this and understand why. This is because of Javascript synchronous and asynchronous processes.

Thanks for the help.