# React: Array contains elements but array.length outputs to console as zero

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

So I want to invoke `addOption` after I update my state, and I know that `setState` in React is asynchronous so I put `addOption` as a callback after `setState` completely executes:

```
  a_method{
    this.setState({
      songRec: songList,
    }, this.addOption);
  }
```

However, in my `addOption` method, when I log out `songRec` I can see that it is clearly updated but its length is still 0 so the `for loop` is never executed.

```
  addOption(){
    const songRec = this.state.songRec;
    var datalist = document.getElementById("data");
    var options = '';
    console.log(songRec);
    console.log(songRec.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < songRec.length; i++){
       //some code//
    }
    datalist.innerHTML = options;
  }
```

This is the output at the console. Line 86 logs `songRec` and line 87 logs `songRec.length`.

[image]

Do you know what is happening and how to get around it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome devtools inconsistency array length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281186/chrome-devtools-inconsistency-array-length)

Comment: Your initial `console.log` clearly shows the array is empty, that's why the loop doesn't run. It gets filled up after the log.

Can it be that you accidentally write `this.state` directly? Is it possible, that you modify the state anywhere else? A lifecycle method maybe? If yes, please update the question with relevant code. 

Do the `console log` statements appear once as expected or several times?

Try outputing `songRec` with a timeout to see if the console log matches the final state that way. You will want to set a timeout similar to when you click the console to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `console.log` does not execute immediately in the line you set it (it kinda varies on each browser), in this case, you should change it to a `debugger` in order to see what is really going on. Is there some specific reason to run this callback function? Can't you use the data that you set on the state to execute this other function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mostly likely caused by the asynchronous function on array. Refer to the following example:

```
function asyncFunction(list){
 setTimeout(function(){
    list.push('a');
    list.push('b');
    list.push('c');
    console.log(list.length); // array length is 3 - after two seconds
 }, 2000); // 2 seconds timeout
}

var list=[];
//getting data from a database
asyncFunction(list);
console.log(list.length) //array is length zero - after immediately
console.log(list) // console will show all values if you expand "[]" after two secon
```

To fix this, a workaround you may need to use is to use a promise for the async part.

```
function asyncFunction(list){
 return new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(function(){
    list.push('a');
    list.push('b');
    list.push('c');
    resolve(list);
    console.log(list.length); // array length is 3 - after two seconds
  }, 2000);  
  });
 // 2 seconds timeout
}

async function getList(){
  var list=[];
  await asyncFunction(list);  
  console.log(list.length) ;
  console.log(list);
}
getList();
```