# Object size changing within the same console.log print?

Tags: javascript, list, browser, console, filtering

See image - **I'm not sure why the values boxed in red are different, and would like to know why.** I want the console to print the values of objects at the time they're printed / be async. I'm not sure why the console seems to be updating values from previous prints and would like to know how to make console.log print like normal code should, line by line / sequential, and for the value that's printed be the same as the value the variable had at the time / for the printed value to not change randomly (especially not in the same print?)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281186/chrome-devtools-inconsistent-array-length . Look at this. Your array might be changing. Take a look at your code, or add a minimal repro example

Comment: You can always include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I was able to fix the list duplication / filtering problem but still the console printing issue remains / how to make console.log be async.